# Calculate RR using relative risk regression

Tags: r, regression

I tried to use the relative risk regression to calculate the Risk ratio but I don't understand how to perform it.
I used the logbin function with glm binomial but I obtain only coefficients

```
fit.glm <- glm(Reparto_OUT ~ t0_IOT , data = db,family=binomial())

install.packages("logbin")
library(logbin)
fit.logbin <- logbin(formula(fit.glm), data = db)
summary(fit.logbin)
```

from this output I don't know how to proceed to obtain the RR with 95% CI

```
> summary(fit.logbin)

Call:
logbin(formula = formula(fit.glm), data = db)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.8761  -0.8388  -0.8388   0.8729   1.5591  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.488334   0.122824 -12.118   <2e-16 ***
t0_FIO1      0.012995   0.001363   9.531   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

    Null deviance: 529.80  on 382  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 434.77  on 381  degrees of freedom
  (1 osservazione eliminata a causa di un valore mancante)

  AIC: 438.77 
AIC_c: 438.80 

Number of iterations: 82 (best: 61)
```

my data:

```
db$Reparto_OUT 
  [1] 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
 [49] 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
 [97] 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
[145] 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
[193] 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
[241] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
[289] 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
[337] 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1

db$t0_FIO1
  [1] 100  21  21  21  21 100  21  21  21  21  21 100 100 100 100  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21
 [25]  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21 100  21  21 100 100  21  21  21 100  21  21  21  21  21  21
 [49]  21  21  21  21 100  21  21  60  21  21  40  21  21 100  21  21  21  21  21  21  21  21 100  21
 [73]  21  21  21  21 100  21  21  21  21  21 100  40  21  21 100  40  21 100  21  21 100  21 100  21
 [97] 100  21  21 100  21  21  40  21  21  40  21  40 100  21  21  21 100  40 100  21  40 100 100  21
[121]  40 100  60  21 100  21 100 100  21 100  60  21  21  40  60  40 100 100 100  40 100  21  21 100
[145] 100 100 100 100  21  21  50  21  21  21  21  21  21  60  80  21  21  21  21 100 100 100 100 100
[169]  21  21  21  21  21  21 100  21 100  21  21  80 100 100 100 100 100  50  21 100 100  21  21  21
[193]  21  21  21  21  21 100  21  21  21  NA  21  21 100 100  70  24  21  60  21  40 100 100  80  28
[217] 100 100  21  21  50  21 100 100 100  31  21  21  21  21  21  21 100  24  21  21  21 100  21  21
[241]  50  21 100 100 100  21 100 100  50  21 100 100  40 100  50  21 100  21  21  21 100  31  21  40
[265]  21  80 100  50  21 100 100 100  40  21  40  60  21  21  21  21  21 100  21  85  21 100 100  60
[289]  21 100 100 100 100 100  21  50  40  50  50  21  40  60  21  50  40  21  21  21 100  21 100 100
[313]  50  21 100  21  21 100  21 100  21  21 100  21  21  21  21  21  21  21 100  21  60  21  21  21
[337]  21 100  21  21  35  21  21  21  70 100 100  80 100  80  21  21  28  21  40  21  60  21  40  21
[361]  21  21  21  21  21  21  80  21  80  50  21  21  21  21  90  80 100  21  21 100 100  21  35 100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `logbin` provides a `confint` to calculate confidence Intervals for login Model parameters. You can use it directly:

[image]
[confint.logbin](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logbin/logbin.pdf)

```
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")

mydata$rank <- factor(mydata$rank)

fit.glm <- glm(admit ~ gre + gpa + rank, data = mydata, family = binomial())

library(logbin)

fit.logbin <- logbin(formula(fit.glm), data = mydata)

confint(fit.logbin)
```

Result is as below:

```
> confint(fit.logbin)
                    2.5 %       97.5 %
(Intercept) -4.4049384197 -1.619052386
gre         -0.0001214211  0.002457373
gpa          0.0722881398  0.866478823
rank2       -0.6276337464 -0.014013695
rank3       -1.1586435941 -0.376578318
rank4       -1.5156930502 -0.394190055
```

You may need to exp(confint(fit.logbin)):

```
> exp(confint(fit.logbin))
                 2.5 %    97.5 %
(Intercept) 0.01221686 0.1980863
gre         0.99987859 1.0024604
gpa         1.07496504 2.3785209
rank2       0.53385354 0.9860840
rank3       0.31391168 0.6862054
rank4       0.21965590 0.6742259
```